# How to reuse the existing mapping configuration when flatten an complex source to destination?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am trying to reuse the existing mapping configuration to flatten a complex source object, which is combined by two simple source objects, the configuration as below:

```
public class Source1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Source1Str { get; set; }
}

public class Source2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Source2Str { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexSource
{
    public Source1 Source1 { get; set; }
    public Source2 Source2 { get; set; }
}

public class Dest
{
    public string Source1Str { get; set; }
    public string Source2Str { get; set; }
}

public class TestProfile : Profile
{
    public TestProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Source1, Dest>();
        CreateMap<Source2, Dest>();
        CreateMap<ComplexSource, Dest>();
    }
}
```

When I am trying to project `IQueryable<ComplextSouce>` to  `IQueryable<Dest>`, the mapping did not happen:

```
 var dests =  (from s1 in _dbContext.Source1 
    join s2 in _dbContext.Source2 on s1.Id equals s2.Id
    select new ComplextObject
    {
        Source1 = s1,
        Source2 = s2
    }).ProjectTo<Dest>().ToList()
```

It seems that Automapper is unable figure out how to map `ComplexSource` to `Dest`, as a result I have to configure each member of `Dest` to map from `ComplexObject`，It is so tedious and unnecessary, how can I simplify this mapping configuration with as little code as possible?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html#includemembers

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu,it works,thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because reading the comments it already has been solved be reading the documentation.